# Return index of highest value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

From an array that looks something like the following, how can I get the index of the highest value in the array. For the array below, the desired result would be '11'.

```
Array (
    [11] => 14
    [10] => 9
    [12] => 7
    [13] => 7
    [14] => 4
    [15] => 6
)
```

Comment: It's been a while, but your array already seems sorted (descending); either it's a bad example or you really just need `reset($arr); echo key($arr);` :)

Answer (score 239, accepted):

My solution is:

```
$maxs = array_keys($array, max($array))
```

***Note:***
 this way you can retrieve **every key** related to a given *max value*.

If you are interested only in *one key among all* simply use **$maxs[0]**

Comment: How to see if two values are same?

Comment: you can check the result if has two or more values if has duplicates

Comment: @AlphaMale you mean two keys I suppose, as the max value is only one by definition ..
@JustinE if you don't want duplicate keys simply search the max (ie avoid `array_keys`) and you'll get only one key corresponding to the max value

Answer (score 50):

```
<?php

$array = array(11 => 14,
               10 => 9,
               12 => 7,
               13 => 7,
               14 => 4,
               15 => 6);

echo array_search(max($array), $array);

?>
```

**array_search() return values:**

Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise.

If needle is found in haystack more than once, the **first matching key** is returned. To return the keys for all matching values, use array_keys() with the optional search_value parameter instead.

Answer (score 12):

I know it's already answered but here is a solution I find more elegant:

```
arsort($array);
reset($array);
echo key($array);
```

and voila!

Comment: the `reset` is not necessary, btw.

Answer (score 5):

Other answers may have shorter code but this one should be the most efficient and is easy to understand.

```
/**
 * Get key of the max value
 *
 * @var array $array
 * @return mixed
*/
function array_key_max_value($array)
{
    $max = null;
    $result = null;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($max === null || $value > $max) {
            $result = $key;
            $max = $value;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick

```
function array_max_key($array) {
  $max_key = -1;
  $max_val = -1;

  foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($value > $max_val) {
      $max_key = $key;
      $max_val = $value;
    }
  }

  return $max_key;
}
```

Comment: Better use the first item’s key and value as the default value.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to get the higher key is as follows:

```
max(array_keys($values['Users']));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$newarr=arsort($arr);
$max_key=array_shift(array_keys($new_arr));
```

Answer (score -8):

Function taken from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

```
function max_key($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if ($val == max($array)) return $key; 
    }
}

$arr = array (
    '11' => 14,
    '10' => 9,
    '12' => 7,
    '13' => 7,
    '14' => 4,
    '15' => 6
);

die(var_dump(max_key($arr)));
```

Works like a charm

Comment: Not to speak about performance. Foreaching through array, checking max value every time is even worse than "bad practice".

Comment: I mentioned its not my implementation. It was a quick and dirty copy/paste that the OP obviously couldn't do himself, mister.

Comment: Not going to lie, you made me chuckle a bit. You're concerned about max() for each iteration through the array? It's "worse than bad practice". No, I don't believe it is. It's not the most elegant, but it works.