# return indexes of the max values in an associative array in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Return index of highest value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461348/return-index-of-highest-value-in-an-array)

How can i return all the index of the max value.. for example a have this array that contains grades of students

```
$grade = array(                       
        "anna"  => "5",
        "lala"=>"7",
        "eni"=>"7",
```

i want to return the names of the student who have the max grade
in this case should print: lala
                           eni

Comment: [what have you tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: On very first search -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461348/return-index-of-highest-value-in-an-array

Comment: I found a same question with a perfect answer for you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461348/return-index-of-highest-value-in-an-array

Answer (score 2):

You can use max()  in order to find the higest value and then do array_keys()  over it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php
E.g.

```
$grade = array(                       
    "anna"  => "5",
    "lala"=>"7",
    "eni"=>"7",

$max = max($grade); // $max == 7
array_keys($grade, $max);
```

Comment: Awesome, didn't know max() did this out of the box.. Thanks for everyone pointing to other answers, but this comes up on top in Google when we search "max associative array php".. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

it looks like a school exercise ...
Ok, you can write something like that:

```
$maxInd = -1;
foreach($grade as $name => $ind) {
    if($ind > $maxInd) {
        $maxInd = $ind;
        $maxRes = array();
    }
    if($ind == $maxInd) {
        $maxRes[] = $name;
    }
}
return "The highest names are " . implode(', ',$maxRes);
```

please, let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

you can do sth. like this:

```
$inversed = Array();        
$highGrade = 0;
foreach ($grade AS $student=>$grade){
  if (isset($inversed[$grade]))
    $inversed[$grade][] = $student;
  else
    $inversed[$grade] = Array($student);

  if ($grade > $highGrade) $highGrade = $grade;
}


print_r($inversed[$highGrade]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$grade = array(  
    "atest" => 6,                     
        "banna"  => "5",
        "lala"=>"7",
        "eni"=>"7");
asort($grade);
$reverse = array_reverse($grade);
$prev_val='';
$counter = 0;
foreach($reverse as $key=>$value)
{
if((($counter==1)&&($value==$prev_val))||($counter==0))
{
echo $key."->".$value."<br/>";
$prev_val = $value;
$counter++;
}
}

?>
```

I have added one more element to the array to clear your doubt.