# How can i identify position of MAX value in array?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get 112 position [01] and use this position[01] to compare something ? Can i do that ? Sorry about stupid question. I'm just a new guy really want to known. Thank for any help.

[image]

```
<?
$sql "SELECT * FROM truck WHERE t_ID = '001'";
$arry = odbc_fetch_array($DataExec);           
echo "MAX value position's".$arry;
?>
```

echo $arry. This 1 i want to show [ MAX value position's 01.]. Or someone have better way.

Comment: You can get it with a php function, but since you're working with SQL... You should know those results are returned from the database in a non-meaningful order.

Comment: Order them and get the result out from SQL itself if possible

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here; what's in your array and what comes out of the query?

Comment: MY teacher order "You have to use SQL and put data into array, then find 'Where max value' and show that position in array. All of these must use PHP.

Comment: Your suggestion to get result by SQL is not match my question. But. thank for any comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$arr_numeric= array('41', '112', '25','54');

$max_position = array_search(max($arr_numeric), $arr_numeric);

echo $max_position;

?>
```

position start from 0.

**OUTPUT**

1

Answer (score 1):

*I get it with a google search.*

```
$maxs = array_keys($array, max($array))
```

Note:
this way you can retrieve every key related to a given max value.

If you are interested only in one key among all simply use `$maxs[0]`

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr =  array('41', '112', '25','54');

$index = array_search(max($arr),$arr);

echo "MAX value position's".$index;
```

[Similar Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461348/return-index-of-highest-value-in-an-array)

Comment: Yeah. Look good. Thank for similiar question.