# Get key of max element in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
$someArray = array('fb' => 32, 'gp' => 11, 'tw' => 7, 'vk' => 89, 'ok' => 112);
```

As you can see last element in array has the greatest value. I need to return the key(`ok`) of last element. How to do this?

Comment: loop through the array, compare till the greatest value..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461363/1641835:

```
$someArray = array('fb' => 32, 'gp' => 11, 'tw' => 7, 'vk' => 89, 'ok' => 112);
$max_keys = array_keys($someArray, max($someArray));
// $max_keys would now be an array: [ 'ok' ]
```

`$max_keys` will now be an array of *all* the keys that point to the maximum value. If you know there will only be one, or you don't care which you retrieve, you could instead use:

```
$someArray = array('fb' => 32, 'gp' => 11, 'tw' => 7, 'vk' => 89, 'ok' => 112);
$max_key = array_search(max($someArray), $someArray);
// $max_key would now be 'ok'
```