# How to get the key/value pair from the highest and lowest array value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a simple array like this:

```
Array(
    [a] =>  1,
    [b] =>  5,
    [c] => 10
)
```

Now I want to get the key/value pair for the highest and lowest array value. Means the expected output would be:

```
//Max value
Key:    c
Value: 10
//Min value
Key:    a
Value:  1
```

I tried something like this:

```
$max_key = max( array_keys( $array ) );
```

Comment: `array_keys($a, max($a))`

Comment: To get the key of the smallest value should be straightforward if you look at the duplicate. (Note that if you use `array_keys()` in your solution you will get an array with **all** keys back from the elements with the highest value, while if you use `array_search()` you will only get the **first key** of the first element with the highest value back).

Comment: _ that just then returns -- just the key and not the value -- need both

Comment: {"label": "super club", "value": 25}

Comment: @TheOldCounty Well from your `max()` and `min()` call you get the highest and lowest value and with `array_keys()`/`array_search()` you can get the corresponding keys. Then you got both keys and values.

Comment: It sounds like a borky way of obtaining the results -- by running two different methods -- a max and a min - twice -- to then glue the results together?

Comment: @TheOldCounty PHP does not provide you with `build_me_a_pink_green_house()` function, but it does provide you with tools like `hammer()` or `screwdriver()`. So with the first calls you can get the values and as you need to with the second call obtain the keys from the values.

Comment: Oh come on man - I was just asking you if there was a cleaner solution

Comment: @TheOldCounty As I was trying to explain to you with the analogy above, PHP does not provide you with a function for everything, but it does provide you with functions to get what you want. So the only thing you can improve is to salve the max/min values first, something like this:  https://3v4l.org/C1VFA Also please don't post solutions inside your question.

Comment: I mean of course you can put that inside a function yourself and then you have created your own function.

Answer (score 1):

Well you almost named then, [max()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) and [min()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) return the max value and min value of array

```
echo max(array(2, 4, 5)); // 5
echo min(array(2, 4, 5)); // 2
```

Comment: -- I need the key name too - not just number

Comment: I tried something like this -- but this didn't work -- it returned just a key -- with a low val -- $max_key = max( array_keys( $mentions ) );

Comment: Please refer to this post then : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461348/return-index-of-highest-value-in-an-array

Comment: @TheOldCounty Don't put your attempt(s) inside the comments. Put them into your question!

Comment: -- yes this comes back with then just the key -- I need KEY and VALUE

Comment: {"label": "super club", "value": 25}