# How to get the highest and lowest Values and sum from Multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have tried using this example here [Return index of highest value in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461348/return-index-of-highest-value-in-an-array)

But that does not go into a multi dimensional Array

I have tried   ARRAY_COLUMN(), array_values(), array_shift, Max and Min but they are not getting the info i need

I want to be able to loop thru and get to:

**[pricing]**

then Check pricing to see which is the highest and lowest in the nested array

so like below  which total was the Highest and lowest trades on these dates

```
[2017-09-22] 
[2017-09-23]
```

obviously  **[2017-09-23]** is a simple one,  i just dint want to add  much more code for ppl helping to go thru.

The Array i create looks like this:

```
 Array
   (
   [2017-09-23] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [timestamp] => 1506169387000
                [pricing] => 9.5470
                [qty] => 25
                [total] => 238.675
                [date] => 2017-09-23
            )

    )

[2017-09-22] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [timestamp] => 1506093083000
                [pricing] => 9.6300
                [qty] => 25
                [total] => 240.75
                [date] => 2017-09-22
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [timestamp] => 1506077220000
                [pricing] => 8.7190
                [qty] => 13
                [total] => 113.347
                [date] => 2017-09-22
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [timestamp] => 1506077109000
                [pricing] => 8.6800
                [qty] => 83
                [total] => 720.44
                [date] => 2017-09-22
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [timestamp] => 1506065258000
                [pricing] => 8.7100
                [qty] => 25
                [total] => 217.75
                [date] => 2017-09-22
            )

    )
```

in the example above i would  like it  to Create a new array with only the following

```
date -> last timestamp -> Highest pricing -> Lowest lowest -> Total of all Totals -> first Timestamp
```

**EDIT:**   the last and first Timestamp are basically  the first and last index  so in this case:

```
[timestamp] => 1506093083000   and    [timestamp] => 1506065258000
```

or  Index [0]  and index [3]

Comment: The last timestamp is the last that appears in order of the array values or a value compare with the other timestamps ?

Comment: i will edit that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array from your question:

```
$array = array (
  '2017-09-23' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'timestamp' => '1506169387000',
      'pricing' => '9.5470',
      'qty' => '25',
      'total' => '238.675',
      'date' => '2017-09-23',
    ),
  ),
  '2017-09-22' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'timestamp' => '1506093083000',
      'pricing' => '9.6300',
      'qty' => '25',
      'total' => '240.75',
      'date' => '2017-09-22',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'timestamp' => '1506077220000',
      'pricing' => '8.7190',
      'qty' => '13',
      'total' => '113.347',
      'date' => '2017-09-22',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'timestamp' => '1506077109000',
      'pricing' => '8.6800',
      'qty' => '83',
      'total' => '720.44',
      'date' => '2017-09-22',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'timestamp' => '1506065258000',
      'pricing' => '8.7100',
      'qty' => '25',
      'total' => '217.75',
      'date' => '2017-09-22',
    ),
  ),
);
```

To get the values maybe you can use `array_map` and with this the function `array_column` is the key of all, try with this:

```
$values = array_map(function($dates) {
    $timestamps = array_column($dates, 'timestamp');
    $pricings = array_column($dates, 'pricing');
    return [
        'max_pricing' => max($pricings),
        'lowest_pricing' => min($pricings),
        'total_of_totals' => array_sum(array_column($dates, 'total')),
        'first_timestamp' => reset($timestamps),
        'last_timestamp' => end($timestamps),
    ];
}, $array);
```

`$values` is an array with the filter values that you need:

```
Array
(
    [2017-09-23] => Array
        (
            [max_pricing] => 9.5470
            [lowest_pricing] => 9.5470
            [total_of_totals] => 238.675
            [first_timestamp] => 1506169387000
            [last_timestamp] => 1506169387000
        )

    [2017-09-22] => Array
        (
            [max_pricing] => 9.6300
            [lowest_pricing] => 8.6800
            [total_of_totals] => 1292.287
            [first_timestamp] => 1506093083000
            [last_timestamp] => 1506065258000
        )

)
```

**EDIT**

Get the pricing of the `[first_timestamp]` and `[last_timestamp]`

```
$values = array_map(function($dates) {
    $timestamps = array_column($dates, 'timestamp');
    $pricings = array_column($dates, 'pricing');
    return [
        'max_pricing' => max($pricings),
        'lowest_pricing' => min($pricings),
        'total_of_totals' => array_sum(array_column($dates, 'total')),
        'first_timestamp' => [
            'value' => reset($timestamps),
            'pricing' => $pricings[each($timestamps)['key']]
        ],
        'last_timestamp' => [
            'value' => end($timestamps),
            'pricing' => $pricings[each($timestamps)['key']]
        ]
    ];
}, $array);
```

I added an array to both timestamps with the value of these and the pricing.

```
Array
(
    [2017-09-23] => Array
        (
            [max_pricing] => 9.5470
            [lowest_pricing] => 9.5470
            [total_of_totals] => 238.675
            [first_timestamp] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 1506169387000
                    [pricing] => 9.5470
                )

            [last_timestamp] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 1506169387000
                    [pricing] => 9.5470
                )

        )

    [2017-09-22] => Array
        (
            [max_pricing] => 9.6300
            [lowest_pricing] => 8.6800
            [total_of_totals] => 1292.287
            [first_timestamp] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 1506093083000
                    [pricing] => 9.6300
                )

            [last_timestamp] => Array
                (
                    [value] => 1506065258000
                    [pricing] => 8.7100
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: its not printing out , did i miss something?

Comment: Use `print_r($values);`

Comment: thats what i did...  and i see why , i didn't notice you called it $array mine was newArray,...  to omany hours working on this!   this works great and i think will help others out too

Comment: i see i messed up a bit.  i need to get  the pricing of the [first_timestamp] and [last_timestamp] as well.   is that something that can be done or need to be a new function ?