# Finding the position of highest value in array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

So i want to find the position of the highest number in this array.

```
$numbers = array($n1, $n2, $n3, $n4, $n5, $n6, $n7, $n8, $n9, $n10);
```

How do i do that?
Thanks

Comment: if you run it through `rsort()`, it will always be the first one :D

Comment: @AlexKarshin but it's O(n log(n)) where maximum of array is just O(n)

Comment: you can use `max()` and `array_keys` to get the position of highest value check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461348/return-index-of-highest-value-in-an-array

Comment: @DanielKrom it was a joke, `rsort()` doesn't maintain the key association :) So the key of the highest value would always be `0` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) can receive an array as a parameter, so with:

```
$numbers = array($n1, $n2, $n3, $n4, $n5, $n6, $n7, $n8, $n9, $n10);
$max = max($numbers);
```

`$max` will have the highest number. Then, use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to get the position:

```
$pos = array_search($max, $numbers);
echo "Position: ".$pos; // Position: 5
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/8lrJj)

Note that the position will be the *index*, so if you want the "real" position, subtract one.