# How to find if a string has all english or arabic letters

Tags: php, regex

I'm taking this question/answer further

[How to check, if a php string contains only english letters and digits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351306/how-to-check-if-a-php-string-contains-only-english-letters-and-digits)

but it's missing special characters check, can we do that?

My objective is to find out if the string has arabic characters but that might be difficult... (if not please advise).

Alternatively we can check if it has all english characters otherwise obviously it would be arabic since I've these two languages only...

Comment: You could try `mb_detect_encoding`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: So you want to ensure that string only contains English or only Arabic characters, correct?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752691/how-to-detect-language-of-text ?

Comment: By special characters, do you mean punctuations, symbols, etc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look for Arabic characters with regexp

```
$is_arabic = preg_match('/\p{Arabic}/', $text);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Answer (score 10):

If it doesn't work, try the following:

```
$is_arabic = preg_match('/\p{Arabic}/u', $text);
```

The PHP preg functions, which are based on PCRE, support Unicode when the /u option is appended to the regular expression, as per http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html.

Answer (score 1):

According to [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html), PCRE is optionally supporting Unicode scripts. So have a closer look [here about scripts](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#script)

`\p{Arabic}` is matching Arabic characters