# How to detect language in JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

I know that in Wordpress we can do the following:

```
preg_match("/\p{Arabic}/u",
get_the_title())
```

How can we do this in JavaScript? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean language or script? Also, what kind of content do you want to do the detecting on?

Comment: I want to know if text is arabic or not using java script.

Comment: [`\p` match generic character types](http://de.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php), not exactly language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know how to detect your language in php then its just a simple matter of passing a value from your php code to your javascript code.

eg.

```
<?php $language = get_language_on_whatever_way_you_want(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function alertMeTheLanguage() {
    var language = '<?php echo $language; ?>';
   alert('Your language is  <?php     echo $language; ?> ' );
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you use a the echo() twice instead of the JS variable `language`?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this via the Google Language API [Detect language from string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441562/detect-language-from-string-in-php)

Comment: I know how to detect language on php, I showed you that I know how! I want to do that on the client side " Java script "

Comment: @zeina: Did you see the answers in that link? There is an example that uses javascript (and AJAX) to detect the language. Javascript alone, as a language, does not have that capability.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to use [qTranslate](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/)?