# server side detect input string lang

Tags: php, parsing, lang

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [detect language from string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441562/detect-language-from-string-in-php)

how can i detect the lang of the user input string?

for exemple the string:

בדיקה בלה בלה heb אחד שתיים שלוש

will give the result: hebrew

10x!

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441562/detect-language-from-string-in-php

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to compare the string with a database of dictionaries, and depending on which dictionary the word is contained within, you can find the language.

However, caveats

- some words will appear in many languages
- Getting hold of all dictionaries for all the languages you wish to support may not be easy.