# How to know if the language of web page is English or not?

Tags: php, detection

I simply want to know if a web page is in English or not. Is there any good way to do it?

The closest I've found is [Detect language from string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441562/detect-language-from-string-in-php) but it is of some use for me..

Any suggestions?

I've a sample non-English [site](http://24-support.com):

Comment: I'd search for the word "the". If it is english, there should be lots of "the"s.

Comment: The above sample site in Russian does contain some "the's" though.

Comment: Related / duplicate question: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/1871/efficient-linguistic-algorithms-for-detecting-language-of-a-website

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there are nearly all/a lot of possiblities to detect a language in your linked question. Why you can not use one of the proposed answers?

One more solution (but not a reliable) ist to look for meta tags with language information like:

```
<meta name="DC.language" content="en" scheme="DCTERMS.RFC3066">
<meta name="keywords" lang="en" content="some content">
<meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">
```

Comment: I've this sample site which does not have lang word in the page: http://24-support.com/

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no perfect one solution, what you need is to have a set of checks and execute them one at a time. You probably want to start with the ones that can detect the language if the html page is well formed as per tonymarschall's answer.

As a fallback check you could use a list of english [stopwords](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words), they are used in search engines to filter out the most common words in a language . In your case you'll have to calculate their occurrences in the text portions of the html page. If they are above a certain value you can make a fairly good guess that you are looking at english text.

Try looking [here](http://armandbrahaj.blog.al/2009/04/14/list-of-english-stop-words/) for a list. Also [this](http://phpir.com/language-detection-with-n-grams) article shows the N-gram approach that you could also use.

Answer (score 1):

I use http://www.alchemyapi.com/ to detect languages.  You take a snippet of the text and pass it to their API.  It detects most languages and is quite accurate.  They offer a free API that allows for 1,000 requests per day which is acceptable for moderate use.  Otherwise the price skyrockets.

You can also try the Google translate API:

http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/v2/getting_started.html#language_detect

Then there's this one:

http://langid.net/identify-language-from-api.html

They offer quite a few requests for free, but I don't know how accurate they are.  Definitely worth a look.

Comment: @AgA I just updated my response with another that allows for up to 1,000 requests per hour for free.

Answer (score 1):

Some projects that might be of interest include:

- The [Chromium Compact Language Detector](http://code.google.com/p/chromium-compact-language-detector/) - C++ / python bindings
  for the language detector from Google Chrome. There are ports to [Javascript](https://github.com/jaukia/cld-js) and other languages [here](https://github.com/mzsanford/cld).
- [Java LangDetect](http://code.google.com/p/language-detection/) -
  Language detection in Java.
- [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/1.3/detection.html#Language_Detection) supports language
  detection.
- [Java extremely simple language identifier](http://tika.apache.org/1.3/detection.html#Language_Detection).