# choose right text direction depending on input

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to build a webpage where two types of users come to my web site. One is the usual English users, and the second one is Persian users ( same text attributes as Arabic, like text direction and text alignment ). So I want to be able to set the text direction of echoed texts depending on users input.

Let me give you an example ;

I have a text input like this :

```
<form name="myform" action="thispage.php" method="post" target="_self">
<input type="text" id="decsription" name="description" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" >
</form>

<?php 

if (isset($_POST['description']))
{
echo '<div align="right" dir="rtl"> Your Chiose is : '.$_POST['description'].'</div>';
}
```

SO, for example if the text input is typed in english, the echo section would change to something like this :

```
echo '<div align="left" dir="ltr"> Your Chiose is : '.$_POST['description'].'</div>';
```

But if the text is non English, then the echo section would be like this :

```
echo '<div align="right" dir="rtl"> انتخاب شما : '.$_POST['description'].'</div>';
```

Is this possible to do ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441562/detect-language-from-string-in-php might be of use here.

Comment: so what ur essentially asking is how to detect typed language with php?

Comment: @redskins80 yes, and then show the text depending on that detected language.

Comment: you could try and use some web API which would be more thorough with their checking..
http://detectlanguage.com/

http://www.alchemyapi.com/api/lang/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function check_eng($str)
{
if (strlen($str) != strlen(utf8_decode($str))) {
return false;
} else {
return true;
}
}
```

`check_eng('hello');` would return true, while `check_eng('で書くタッチイベント (フ');` would return false.

Works 99% of the time.

Demonstration: http://codepad.viper-7.com/k0PlKU

For your situation, you'd just check the string with this function, and if it returned false use the right-to-left orientation.

Comment: unfortunately not working with Persian and English languages.

Comment: @Siwa works fine for me. Made a specific example here http://codepad.viper-7.com/S2gVUV