# checking which language from textarea

Tags: php, unicode, textarea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect language from string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441562/detect-language-from-string-in-php)

How do I change the class of a textarea based on the language it contains (arabic, spanish, etc)?

Comment: Please try to make your question more clear. What does ** echoing a class value to according to its language.** mean

Comment: Probably not, at least not reliably.  For example, if I simply enter the word "no", what language would that be?

Comment: @TheCOMPLETEPHPNewbie better?

Comment: @David Italian. [**DUUUH**](http://translate.google.com/#it/en/No)

Comment: @Neal Spanish! That's what Google told me.

Comment: maybe `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']` can help you a little, just a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your orignial question mentions arabic.

If by detecting language you mean arabic vs. english *characters*, then you can use this:

```
preg_match('/[\x{0600}-\x{06FF}]/ui', $string)
```

Considering your input is in UTF-8 encoding, [the character range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Arabic) for arabic is U+0600 to U+06FF, for some other language it's another set of characters, etc.