# PHP Detect if non-english

Tags: php

I am using these code to check if a string is in English or not.

```
<?php
    $string="で書くタッチイベント (フ";

    if(!preg_match('/[^\W_ ] /',$string)) {
        echo "Please enter English words only:(";
    } else {
        echo "OK, English Detected!";
    }
?>
```

It cant provide perfect result because string like `"some english text で書くタッチイベント (フ"` this also detects as English language, any idea?

Comment: Define "english". For letters only the trivial `/^[a-zA-Z]*$/` would only match "english".

Comment: Do you mean 'actual English' or do you mean 'containing more Latin characters than kanji/kana'?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try this (please note you need mbstring php module installed):

```
<?php
    $string="で書くタッチイベント (フ";

    if(strlen($string) != mb_strlen($string, 'utf-8'))
    { 
        echo "Please enter English words only:(";
    }
    else {
        echo "OK, English Detected!";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Seems not working... http://ideone.com/obm95F

Comment: Sorry, it was missing utf-8 encode in mb_strlen. Should work now.

Comment: Perfect... Nice work...

Comment: Anyway, this is a must read for every programmer: http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: thanks... good use of  utf-8 :)

Comment: Warning: Some websites rewrite quotation marks to their Unicode variant. Which will trip this as non-English. Example: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm

Comment: Here's a good reference: http://billposer.org/Linguistics/Computation/UnicodeRanges.html

Answer (score 0):

You can not detect the language from the character type. And there are no foolproof ways to do this.

With any method, you're just doing an educated guess. From: [Detect language from string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441562/detect-language-from-string-in-php)

Though some of the below articles may get handy in case..

http://papermashup.com/php-language-detection/

https://github.com/BruceJillis/PHP-Language-Detection

http://phpir.com/language-detection-with-n-grams/

Hope it helps..

Comment: Does this answer say anything not copy/pasted from that other question?

Comment: Why do you guys downvote his comments? It's absolutely true...

Comment: @Chris I did not downvote, but comments should not be posted as answers. Also, if Hiren believes this question is already answered elsewhere, than he/she should mark the OP as duplicate.

Comment: @Chris: Because there is already a mechanism for directing users to answers that someone else has already provided: voting to close the question as a duplicate. Even if you don't want to do that, instead of *copy/pasting* from the answers of others one can always leave a comment linking to them.

Comment: Courtesy has been given... And I had some articles so shared as the code is much larger..

Comment: @HirenPandya If you believe you have further to contribute to this topic, than you should post a new answer to the original question and mark the current question as duplicate.

Comment: I can not mark it as duplicate.. Rather than down voting it and discourage the OP, I had some of the articles which is not posted in the given stackoverflow link.. So posted. But next time, I will keep this in mind... Thank you.

Comment: @HirenPandya Why can't you flag the OP?

Comment: I do not have that privilege to perform mentioned action...

Comment: @HirenPandya Flagging for moderator attention is a privilege given to any user with 15 reputation points and up.

Comment: But it is not available to me though.. Tried so many times.. People here, told me that you should not post only link to the duplicate question so I put some my efforts to provide a better answer...

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!preg_match('/[^\w ]/u',$string))
```