# How to check if the set of characters are german or indian (maybe with character range)

Tags: php, regex

I need to know if the given string is in German, Indian or Persian.

Checking for Lating or non-Latin, I simply use `[a-zA-Z]` regExp, but I don't know what should I do when I have two non-Latins and a German language.

Do we have any character-range other than `[a-zA-Z]`, maybe with code range, if exists at all.

Something like this:

```
$string = "MyCharactersInGermanlanguage";

$res = preg_match("/[characterRangeOfgermanLanguage]/", $string);
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: German does not have an overly broad set of extended Latin characters to detect it with. Indian and Persian do. See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html

Comment: @mario would you explain more

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the unicode support?

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

You might also want to look here for ways to detect the language from the string:

[Detect language from string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441562/detect-language-from-string-in-php)

Comment: Well, I need more explanations

Answer (score 0):

The full set of german letters:

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZäÄöÖüÜß

---

The php regex to match the characters is:

```
[A-Za-z\xC4\xD6\xDC\xDF\xE4\xF6\xFC]+
```